# making images scalable for responsive designs

Tags: responsive

Working on first responsive website template; layout is part fluid, with fixed sidebars, using media queries. I want to have some of my images be scalable. Per this article http://www.blissfulinterfaces.com/making-wordpress-images-responsive/ it should be very simple, at least for manually loaded images. Add this to stylesheet:

```
img{max-width: 100%;}
img{ -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

and manually remove width and heights that wp automatically adds. Have done both and not a thing happens.

See images in the main areas (not sidebars) on these 2 pages: http://66.147.244.110/~rdbikeco/wheelbuilding.html and http://66.147.244.110/~rdbikeco/aboutus.html

I haven't added code to functions for thumbnails yet -- wanted to get the basics working first.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: That's a pure CSS question, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing appears to happen because the size of the images is smaller than the available width. If I add a bunch of padding to the container in Chrome and then resize the window, the image scales once all horizontal width is consumed.